# Can Jersey-Json/Jackson be configured to produce json-rpc-1.0?

Tags: java, jersey, jackson, json-rpc

I have an api that I need to call that uses json-rpc-1.0 (I have no control of the implementation).  I'd like to be able to manipulate jaxb objects and have them marshal into json-rpc-1.0 format.  Is this something that jackson/jersey-json can accomplish or is there a different library that can achieve this goal?

Comment: I am not too familiar with json rpc but wouldn't you be able to serialize correctly by naming your fields appropriately? Also take a look at custom serializes (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers) that may be what you re looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Jersey cannot be configured to support JSON-RPC, but Jersey could be used to implement JSON-RPC. JSON-RPC specifies a protocol with requests and responses and can be implemented over HTTP. Jersey (and all JAX-RPC implementations) can be used to implement any HTTP based protocol.

However, since the latest JSON-RPC spec (2.0 - http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) does not specify how request and responses are mapped to HTTP verbs (POST, GET, etc.) and status codes, there could be some incompatibilities between JSON-RPC implementations.

Instead of using Jersey to implement JSON-RPC, you might be better off using an existing JSON-RPC implementation, see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC#Implementations